# Javascript / jQuery use old DOM object in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I retrieve a table with the following script:

```
$("#table").load("index #table", function(tableNew) { // code });
```

Before I do this, I like to store the old table in a variable. When retrieving the new table, I want to compare it with the old table.

```
var tableCurrent = document.getElementById('table');
console.log(tableCurrent); // object

$("#table").load("index #table", function(tableNew) {
   var htmlNew = $.parseHTML(tableNew);
   var rowsNew = htmlNew[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

   console.log(tableCurrent); // null

   // compare new with old

   // insert new table in DOM
});
```

How can I 'access' the old table inside the 'load' callback? I know the old table will be removed which is correct.

Comment: before `.load` store it in a variable.

Comment: `tableCurrent` should still be available in the callback. Since you're using jquery, store it as a jquery object and let the jquery cache handle it.

Comment: @lolka_bolka This is what he did with `tableCurrent`

Comment: @Brian `tableCurrent` is a `reference`to the table and when `load` callback is executed the table in the DOM is overwriten so the reference too. That's why `console.log(tableCurrent` returns `null`.

Comment: @dnns You should try to use `$.ajax` and make the overwrite of your table "manually".

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ yes, creating the jquery object will have a different reference. I updated my comment as well as added an answer demonstrating it.

Comment: I know that it's a reference. Is it possible to store the DOM object without a reference?

Comment: @dnns Take a look to my previous comment to you

Comment: Yes, I saw it after posting that comment. Thanks for helping. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Store as jquery object to avoid hitting the old reference as the new jQuery object is not a reference to the old table DOM element

```
var tableCurrent = document.getElementById('table');
console.log(tableCurrent); // object
var $tableCurrent = $('#table');

$("#table").load("index #table", function(tableNew) {
   var htmlNew = $.parseHTML(tableNew);
   var rowsNew = htmlNew[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

   console.log($tableCurrent); // this should be the jquery table object
   console.log($tableCurrent[0]); // actual table element

   // compare new with old

   // insert new table in DOM
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.